# Updating default values of a React-Hook-Form, does not populate filelds with useFieldArray

Tags: javascript, react-hook-form

This problem has consumed a lot of time trying to figure out what is wrong. I have a React-Hook-Form (v6.14.1) that needs to populate dynamic data, based on the component state.
On the initial load, everything works fine. If I change the state all updated data are displaying fine, except the dynamic data.

[Here is a codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-pond-tbzz2u?file=/src/App.js). If it does not render due to a library error, just hit the preview refresh button.

The goal is that the WAN 1 tab, on initial load displays the dynamic fields (WAN 1 VLAN-1) and WAN2 does not have dynamic fields to display. Hitting the `Update Config` button, WAN1 should not have dynamic fields to display and WAN2 should display one (WAN 2 VLAN-1). The problem is that WAN2 does not display it.

I have searched for similar questions, but all of them were about the values of the populated fields and not about displaying the fields themselves. I have used the `reset` method of react-hook-form and the `defaltValue` for each dynamic field as react-hook-form documentation suggests.

On **App.js** I have the state, a button that updates the state, and the `Form` component which has the state as property.

```
  const [configdata, setConfigdata] = useState(config);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UpdateConfig onClick={() => setConfigdata(configUpdated)} />
      <Form
        formData={configdata}
        handleFormData={(data) => console.log(data)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

On **Form.js** there is a Rect-hook-form `FormProvider` and the `WanFields` component that dynamically populates form fields.

```
<FormProvider {...methods}>
            <form
              onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) =>
                props.handleFormData(data)
              )}
            >
              <Tab.Content>
                {props.formData?.intfs?.length &&
                  props.formData?.intfs.map((intf, index) => (
                    <Tab.Pane key={index} eventKey={`wan${index}-tab`}>
                      <WanFields
                        key={`wan${index}-fields`}
                        intfNo={index}
                        portTypeOptions={props.portTypeOptions}
                        data={intf}
                      />
                    </Tab.Pane>
                  ))}
              </Tab.Content>
            </form>
          </FormProvider>
```

Every time the `props.formData` update, there is a `useEffect` that `reset` the forms' default data.

```
const methods = useForm({ defaultValues: props.formData });

  useEffect(() => {
    methods.reset(props.formData);
  }, [props.formData]);
```

In **WanFields.js**, there are all the form fields, and the `useFieldArray` method, that will populate the dynamic fields based on the forms' default values and a `watch` field value (`watchIntfType` ).

```
const methods = useFormContext();
  const { errors, control, watch, register } = methods;
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    keyName: "fieldid",
    name: `intfs[${intfNo}].subIntfs`
  });

  const watchIntfStatus = watch(`intfs[${intfNo}].enabledStatus`);
  const watchIntfType = watch(`intfs[${intfNo}].enabled`);
```

Dynamic fields are populated as follows

```
{watchIntfType?.value >= "2" && (
            <>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="btn btn-success" onClick={append}>
                  Add
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id={`accordion-${intfNo}`}>
                <Accordion>
                  {console.log("FIELDS", fields)}
              // This is where the problem starts. fields are empty after updating data
                  {fields.map((field, index) => {
                    return (
                      <Card key={field.fieldid}>
                        <Accordion.Toggle
                          as={Card.Header}
                          variant="link"
                          eventKey={`${index}`}
                          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        >
                          <h4>
                            WAN {parseInt(intfNo) + 1}{" "}
                            <span style={{ margin: "0px 5px" }}>
                              <i className="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </span>{" "}
                            VLAN-{index + 1}
                          </h4>
                          <div className="card-header-action">
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              className="btn btn-danger"
                              onClick={() => remove(index)}
                            >
                              Remove
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </Accordion.Toggle>

                        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={`${index}`}>
                          <Card.Body>
                            <div className="form-row">
                              <div className="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
                                <label>IP</label>
                                <input
                                  type="text"
                                  className="form-control"
                                  name={`intfs[${intfNo}].subIntfs[${index}].ipAddress`}
                                  defaultValue={field?.ipAddress}
                                  ref={register()}
                                />
                              </div>
                              <div className="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
                                <label>Subnet</label>
                                <input
                                  type="number"
                                  className="form-control"
                                  min="0"
                                  max="30"
                                  name={`intfs[${intfNo}].subIntfs[${index}].subnet`}
                                  defaultValue={field?.subnet}
                                  ref={register()}
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </Card.Body>
                        </Accordion.Collapse>
                      </Card>
                    );
                  })}
                </Accordion>
              </div>
            </>
          )}
```

The problem is that when the state updates, form default values are updated, but the method `useFieldArray` attribute `fields` are not updated and stay as an empty array. I really cannot understand, what I am doing wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if is a correct method but i have resolv this probleme with method reset in a useEffect.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset

```
defaultValues: 
{
  acvDesignOffice: generateRSEnv.acvDesignOffice,
  earthQuakeZone: generateRSEnv.earthQuakeZone,
  buildings: generateRSEnv.buildings,
},

useEffect(() => {

reset({
  acvDesignOffice: generateRSEnv.acvDesignOffice,
  earthQuakeZone: generateRSEnv.earthQuakeZone,
  buildings: generateRSEnv.buildings,
});
}, [generateRSEnv]);
```